# Using Trapperkeeper with the reloaded pattern

Tags: web-services, clojure

I’m trying to use the reloaded pattern with [Trapperkeeper](https://github.com/puppetlabs/trapperkeeper/blob/master/documentation/Reloaded-Pattern.md). But it doesn’t seem to be working with the declared dependencies in my `defservice`.

Now, I put the init, start, stop, etc , functions in a namespace. And **i)** after running trapper keeper with `lein run --config ...`, with a repl service, or **ii)** manually starting up a repl. I can’t reload with `reset`.

When I try to run `(reset)` or `(go)` from a repl, I get the error: `RuntimeException Service ':WebroutingService' not found`.

And in **bootstrap.cfg** , I definitely have that service configured:

```
puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.services.webrouting.webrouting-service/webrouting-service
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you also add the service to the `tk/build-app` form in the `init` function?

```
(tk/build-app
  [...
   puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.services.webrouting.webrouting-service/webrouting-service] 
{...})`
```

if you want to use your `bootstrap.cfg` you would have to specify it like this:

```
(tk/build-app
            (bootstrap/parse-bootstrap-config! "./path/to/bootstrap.cfg")
            (config/load-config "./path/to/config.conf")))
```

Comment: Yep, that was exactly it. Cheers.